# If my XML document instruction specifies encoding of UTF-8 do I still need to escape characters?

Tags: ruby, xml, encoding, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I know I need to escape these in all cases:

```
quot  "
amp   &
apos  '
lt    <
gt    >
```

But what about international characters that have accents, or Russian characters to name a couple. Do I need to escape characters of this type when my encoding instruction is set to UTF-8?

What If I were to set the encoding instruction to ASCII? Would I need to escape all those characters also?

This is a sample of the XML (from a legacy system) I am trying to reproduce using Nokogiri(lib2xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <DESCRIPTION lang="rus">
    <SHORT_DESCRIPTION>&#1052;&#1054;&#1044;&#1059;&#1051;&#1068;- ELECTRONIC  OUTPUT 120 V DC 5 mA</SHORT_DESCRIPTION>
    <LONG_DESCRIPTION>&#1052;&#1054;&#1044;&#1059;&#1051;&#1068;- &#1058;&#1048;&#1055; ELECTRONIC  OUTPUT &#1042;&#1061;&#1054;&#1044; 120 V DC &#1042;&#1067;&#1061;&#1054;&#1044; 5 mA &#1048;&#1057;&#1058;&#1054;&#1063;&#1053;&#1048;&#1050; &#1055;&#1048;&#1058;&#1040;&#1053;&#1048;&#1071; 120 V DC &#1044;&#1054;&#1055;&#1054;&#1051;&#1053;&#1048;&#1058;&#1045;&#1051;&#1068;&#1053;&#1040;&#1071; &#1044;&#1045;&#1058;&#1040;&#1051;&#1068; 1 ANALOG SM322-8S TOR</LONG_DESCRIPTION>
 </DESCRIPTION>
```

You can see that the instruction in the sample says UTF-8 but they have escaped a lot of characters, characters that Nokogiri only escapes when I specify an ASCII encoding instruction. This is what is confusing me.

EDIT 2 : If I do not pass an encoding instruction to Nokogiri, the resulting XML leaves all the Russian characters in their native Cyrillic alphabet, BUT that would not be consistent with the XML I need to replicate.

Comment: No you don't. But make sure you actually encode the file as UTF-8... simply having the attribute `encoding="UTF-8"` doesn't make it so.

Comment: Esailija makes a good point. There are two things here - the declared encoding, which tells the parser the document encoding, and the encoding used to write character data to encoded octets. They have to match or the parser uses the wrong one and corrupts the data when it reads it.

Comment: I added a sample pf the xml I need to replicate, it says encoding UTF-8  in the instructions but escapes characters that should not be escaped because they are valid UTF-8.

Comment: The updated sample is still likely to be legal UTF-8, but this is probably a hack because at some point someone developing one of the systems (producer, consumer(s) or intermediary layers) didn't really understand UTF-8 or had to work with technology that thought it did but didn't.

Comment: It sounds like I have two choices, tell the xml builder UTF-8 and trust that it escapes all characters that are non UTF-8 and force the non complying consuming system to change, OR hack my output to match the legacy version, escaping all non ascii characters. If I choose the former I could have a battle on my hands.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to represent a character with a character reference if either:

- It would have special meaning in the current context (so the five characters you listed only need encoding sometimes)
- It does not exist in the character encoding the file is encoded in

ASCII doesn't have many characters in it, so if you encoded your XML in ASCII you would have to use character references for many characters.

Don't encode your XML in ASCII. The default encoding for XML is UTF-8, which is very well supported.

Comment: I edited the question to add more detail. Should I assume that if libxml2 does not escape a character when I specify the UTF-8 encoding instruction then it is valid and should be valid in all xml parsers?

Comment: Yes. (-------------------- StackOverflow doesn't like short answers so I'm making it long)